# Classpaths and command-line switches (-cp, -D)

Tags: java, classpath

I'm having much difficulty running my jar file, probably because I'm not sure the proper syntaxes to use when using various switches on the commandline. Here's what I have:

`java -classpath %appdata%\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\mp3spi.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\jl.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\tritonus.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar; net.minecraft.client.Minecraft username password server.com:25565 -D java.library.path=%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar`

I need to have all of those things included in my classpath, and also set `-D` to the value I have.

Can someone help me identify the problem? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your options (classpath with `-classpath`, system properties with `-D`) first, then your class (`net.minecraft.client.Minecraft`), finally the class arguments (`username`, `password`, ...).

Also, it's `-Dproperty=value`, with no blank separating the `-D` and your setting.
Finally, `java.library.path` points to a directory, not a file.

Here's the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: `java -classpath %appdata%\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\mp3spi.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\jl.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\tritonus.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar; -Djava.library.path=%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft username password server.com:25565` I still get: `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.libr
ary.path` Any help? :/

Comment: The website of the library I'm trying to use tells me to do what I am already doing: `Specify the path to it using -Djava.library.path=<path/to/library>` But that doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Ah well thanks for the info, now I have other errors but I'll figure them out :)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the doc. Can't believe how hard it is to find.